# sqlalchemy list connections inside connection pool

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, connection-pooling

I made a connection with sqlalchemy to mssql and I used queue pool. I am trying to understand this connetion pool is worked or not. and also I want to see the connections and the queue inside connection pool how can I see?

```
engine = sal.create_engine('IP',pool_size=1,max_overflow=0)
result = engine.execute('select * from mytable')
result.close()
```